# How to load 2 or more entity from OData before View is loaded

Tags: sapui5

I am developing a Master-Detail App.

I have 1 EntityType for Master View (Master) and another EntityType for Detail (Detail). I have created an Association from Master to Detail.

Master View works perfectly.
Detail has 2 parts:

1. Header: which shows a few fields from the Line selected in Master view. (Name, ID and not much more)
2. Body: it has 2 fragments. These 2 fragments displays the info from Detail Entity.

My Issue is:

- I got errors in the Console cause fields loaded on Fragments are searched from the Entity type Master. It means that the View && Fragments are loaded before the second Binding is done.

What I have tried:

- I used the BusyIndicator and controlling the events (`attachRequestComplete` and/or `attachEventOnce("dataReceived")`) from the Model in the `onInit()` assigning `view.setBusy(false)` when they are reached. It doesn't work for me.
- I tried it out but when the Event of the 2nd binding is reached the view is already loaded.

*After loading the info in **Master View**:*

```
function _onUpdateFinished(event) {
    var sPath = selItem.getBindingContextPath().substr(1);
    router.navTo("detail", {
                contextPath: sPath
            });
}
```

*When I load the information in **Detail View**:*

```
onInit:function(){
   this.getRouter().attachRoutePatternMatched(_onRoutePatternMatched, this);
},

_onRoutePatternMatched( oEvent ){
   var sPath = "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").contextPath;
   view.bindElement({ path: sPath,
                      events: {
                        change: function (oEvent) {
                        },
                        dataRequested: function () {},
                        dataReceived: function (oResponse) {
                            view.byId("iconTabBar").bindElement({
                              path: "Master2Detail",
                              events: {
                                    change: function (oEvents) {
                                    },
                                    dataRequested: function () {},
                                    dataReceived: function (oRespon) {
                                        view.setBusy(false);
                                    }
                               }
                            });
                        }
                        }
                    });
    }
```

*I would really appreciate your inputs.*

I was thinking on passing as parameters the values from Master view for the Header section and call the Detail entity from Backend, in that way I have only 1 Call and I assume, it would work by using the onInit() with Events...

The Detail View code is:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:fsem="sap.f.semantic" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    controllerName="app.masterDetail.controller.Detail">
    <f:DynamicPage id="detailPage" showFooter="true" stickySubheaderProvider="iconTabBar" class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
        <f:title>
            <f:DynamicPageTitle>
                <f:heading>
                    <Title text="i18n>DETAIL_VIEW" wrapping="true"/>
                </f:heading>
                <f:actions>
                    <Button id="btnTrsNew" text="{i18n>DETAIL_NEW}" type="Transparent" press="onNewFile" visible="{screenSetup>/bNewRequest}"/>
                    <Button id="btnTrsSave" text="{i18n>DETAIL_SAVE}" type="Transparent" press="onSaveNew" visible="{screenSetup>/bSaveCredit}"/>
                    <Button id="btnTrsCancel" text="{i18n>DETAIL_CANCEL}" type="Transparent" press="onCancel" visible="{screenSetup>/bCancel}"/>
                </f:actions>
                <f:expandedContent>
                    <Label text="{i18n>DETAIL_NAME}: {Name}"/>
                </f:expandedContent>
                <f:navigationActions>
                    <PagingButton id="paging" count="{ui>/paging/detailCount}" position="{ui>/paging/detailPosition}" positionChange="onPositionChange"
                        visible="{= ${ui>/uiState/actionButtonsInfo/midColumn/exitFullScreen} !== null || ${device>/isPhone} || ${device>/isTablet}}"/>
                    <Button type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://full-screen" visible="{= ${ui>/uiState/actionButtonsInfo/midColumn/fullScreen} !== null}"
                        press="onFullScreenPress"/>
                    <Button type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://exit-full-screen"
                        visible="{= ${ui>/uiState/actionButtonsInfo/midColumn/exitFullScreen} !== null}" press="onFullScreenExitPress"/>
                    <Button type="Transparent" icon="sap-icon://decline" visible="{= ${ui>/uiState/actionButtonsInfo/midColumn/closeColumn} !== null}"
                        press="onClose"/>
                </f:navigationActions>
            </f:DynamicPageTitle>
        </f:title>
            <IconTabBar id="iconTabBar" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" tooltip="{i18n>DETAIL_AMOUNT}" expandable="false">
                <items>
                    <IconTabFilter id="currentDetailTab" key="currentDetail" icon="sap-icon://business-one">
                        <core:Fragment id="DetailAmount" fragmentName="app.masterDetail.view.fragments.currentDetail"/>
                    </IconTabFilter>
                    <IconTabFilter id="statusDetailTab" key="statusDetail" icon="sap-icon://bbyd-active-sales" tooltip="{i18n>DETAIL_STATUS}">
                        <core:Fragment id="DetailStatus" fragmentName="app.masterDetail.view.fragments.statusDetail"/>
                    </IconTabFilter>
                </items>
            </IconTabBar>
        </f:content>
        <f:footer>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <content>
                    <Button id="btnMessages" type="Emphasized" text="{=${messages>/}.length}" icon="sap-icon://message-popup" press="onShowMessages"
                        visible="{=${messages>/}.length > 0}"/>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <Button id="btnNew" text="{i18n>DETAIL_NEW}" type="Emphasized" press="onNewFile" visible="{screenSetup>/bNewRequest}"/>
                    <Button id="btnSave" text="{i18n>DETAIL_SAVE}" type="Emphasized" press="onSaveNew" visible="{screenSetup>/bSaveCredit}"/>
                    <Button id="btnCancel" text="{i18n>DETAIL_CANCEL}" type="Reject" press="onCancel" visible="{screenSetup>/bCancel}"/>
                </content>
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </f:footer>
    </f:DynamicPage>
</mvc:View>
```

This will be a Fragment with SmartField:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:smartForm="sap.ui.comp.smartform"
    xmlns:smartField="sap.ui.comp.smartfield">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin" id="creditLimitStatusVBox">
        <smartForm:SmartForm id="sFormStatus" editTogglable="false" editToggled="handleEditToggled" title="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_TITLE}">
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_STATUS}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{Status}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_ENDDATE}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{Enddate}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_DELIVERY}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{DeliveryId}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
        </smartForm:SmartForm>
        <smartForm:SmartForm id="sFormItem" editTogglable="false" editToggled="handleEditToggled" title="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_ITEM}">
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_MATERIAL}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{Material}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_QUANTITY}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{Quantity}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
                <smartForm:GroupElement label="{i18n>FRG_STATUS_AMOUNT}">
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{Amount}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
        </smartForm:SmartForm>
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: can you add your xml view/show how you place the fragment there? I guess you mixed up the binding path declarations

Comment: Hi bkr, 

I have added the Detail view code and the smallest Fragment - the other is basically the same but with 20 fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code binds relative the path "Master2Detail" on the detail side. BUT initially there should not be any existing binding in any parent view.

Your app should look more or less like this for binding path. UI5 is moving up the element to find data:

> App-> Flexible ColumnLayout/SPlitView -> Master

> App-> Flexible ColumnLayout/SPlitView -> Details

So adjust your bindings a described here [OData error when bind to an element in a Master-Detail app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683268/odata-error-when-bind-to-an-element-in-a-master-detail-app/67701955#67701955)

Second, you get this error because initially there is no relative binding in between your master bound element and the detail. Therefore, UI5 can only think this must be part of the master.

If you make up a relative binding in-between, you must inject the fragment by yourself. E.g. [load the fragment](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.17/code/webapp/controller/HelloPanel.controller.js), bind the loaded control(in aour case the VBox) and then use [addItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.IconTabBar%23methods/addItem) etc. do attache it to the view.

Comment: Hi bkr,

thanks for your answers! what I do is to bind the Selected Item to the Detail view first. Once it is linked, I go for the Association. I do this cause the Detail view uses some fields from the Selected Item from Master View and Tabs are all linked to the Detail Entity.

I tried the "Expand" option but I don't know how to create a new entry ```createEntry("<entityType>", {Object});```. In the Detail view I had ```<Text text="{<expand/field1>}"``` and the returned oContext should be bound with the same "name" as the expanded...

Comment: hi bkr, it took me for a while but it works as you explained with the relative Path. 
I am calling the Tabs once the event ```DataReceived``` is triggered from the expand.